# How to check an xml file exist in Resources android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-resources, file-exists

I have an `xml` file inside the res folder under the `xml` folder. I need to check if this file exist. I used `getidentifier` to check existence but I got error.

[image]

As in shown in the picture. I have an integer named checkExistence to go on if checkExistence=1 (if file exist). But application does not work. What might be causing this?

Comment: Better you put the code in the question and give the error you are facing instead giving an image of the code.

Comment: Put the line inside the "onCreate". The context might not be available outside.

Comment: to see whether an XML file exists in xml folder is a development-time check. During development you don't need to make code that sees if an XML file exists. You can check the file yourself

Answer (score 0):

Well finally I solved this problem.. What I have done is :

```
Context context=this;
int checkExistence;
```

..

..

..

```
final String resourcename= String.valueOf(R.xml.xmlfiletocheck);
    checkExistence = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resourcename,"xml",context.getPackageName());
```

..

..

```
if(checkExistence!=0) {
//if number is different than 0, it means file exists
..
..
}
```

Comment: if the XML file doesn't exist, besides not existing it will cause your code to not compile